# Extending RequestMappingHandlerMapping to register alternate URL patterns

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

The web applications that we write require bilingual urls.  We previously used "plain Spring/Spring MVC", but we've started transitioning to Spring boot.

In our older Spring 3.x/4.x applications, we solved this problem by unwinding most of the "autoconfig" in order to override the **getMappingPathPatterns** to include a translated version of the URL.  For example:

```
@Override
protected Set<String> getMappingPathPatterns(RequestMappingInfo info) {
    Set<String> unilingualPatterns = super.getMappingPathPatterns(info);
    Set<String> bilingualPatterns = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String pattern : unilingualPatterns) {
        bilingualPatterns.add(pattern);
        // Create the French and English URLs.
        // "resolver" translates the english URL to French.
        final String fraURL = resolver.convertUrl(pattern, Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);

        if (!pattern.equals(fraURL)) {
            bilingualPatterns.add(fraURL);
        }
    }

    return bilingualPatterns;
}
```

This way, a controller that has a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public String homeView() {
    return "home";
}
```

Would automatically have a 2nd mapping of "/accueil".  In essence it would be as if the method were actually annotated like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/home", "/accueil"})
public String homeView() {
    return "home";
}
```

As I mentioned above, this required unwinding a lot of the "auto config", which made for a much more complicated setup.

We're starting to use Spring Boot for new projects, and one of our goals is to reduce the complexity of our configuration.  I was hoping to find a cleaner way to include this functionality.

I've tried creating my own **RequestMappingHandlerMapping** bean in a Configuration class, but it doesn't get used.  In fact, it seems Spring doesn't really want you to override this class anyhow.

After that, I tried getting a hold of the **RequestMappingHandlerMapping** that Spring Boot creates, iterating through the list of **handlerMethods**, and adding new ones for translated **PatternsRequestCondition**, but the map that I get back from **RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods()** is unmodifiable, so that's a dead end as well.

I feel like I'm going down the wrong path anyhow.  I've found that when using Spring, if my solution is getting complicated (like this one is), then I'm doing it wrong and I just need to find the "easy way".

If anybody has any idea of how I can manually add add new HandlerMethods (basically duplicating the existing ones, but with translated URL patterns), that would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a number of different solutions, the one that seemed the "most standard" was to use a single properties file for URLs. This is how I accomplished this with Spring Boot.

First, I created a new properties file called **urls.properties** under **scr/main/resources** that would contain the urls for my application, for example:

```
url.home=/home
url.start=/start
```

I added a **@PropertySource** annotation to my WebConfig configuration file:

```
/**
 * Web configuration.
 *
 * Since 1.0.0
 */
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:i18n/urls.properties")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Locale resolver.
     *
     * @return <code>LocaleResolver</code>
     */
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.CANADA);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Locale change interceptor.
     *
     * @return <code>LocaleChangeInterceptor</code>
     */
    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

This gives me access to these properties in my controllers.

```
/**
 * Demo API controller.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${url.home}")
public class DemoController {

    /**
     * Demo GET method binding.
     *
     * @return <code>String</code>
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

And made sure the **urls.properties** properties file was listed as a property source in my **application.properties** file.

```
spring.messages.basename=messages,urls
```

This gives me access to these urls in my Thymeleaf templates. For example:

```
<a th:href="@{#{url.home}}">Home</a>
```

Having the **@PropertySource** annotation also provides easy access to the urls in test cases, for example:

```
/**
 * DemoController test class.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public class DemoControllerTest extends AbstractMockMvcTest {

    @Value("${url.home}")
    private String urlHome;

    /**
     * Test get username.
     *
     * @throws Exception Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void getUsername() throws Exception {
        // Request.
        resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(urlHome));
        // Verify response.
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Now, when it's time to translate the urls, just the urls.properties file needs to be sent off for translation.  It's important to note that this will still just be a single file (no _en and _fr variants), so the file will end up looking like:

```
url.home=/home-accueil
url.start=/start-debut
```

I hope this helps somebody else.  It was a pain to figure out the best way to make this work.

If somebody else comes up with a better way to do this (that doesn't require hacking Spring too much), please let me know!

Thanks.